# Arrange output.txt using python?

Tags: python, numpy

I need the output in a text file with specific arrangements.e.g,

```
  0.2500000   0.2500000   0.0000000   1.0000000
  0.2400000   0.2400000   0.0000000.  1.0000000
```

so I use a code as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import math
kz=0.0000000
kx = 0.0000000
ky = 0.0000000
theta=0.01000
K =[kx, ky, kz, 1.00000000]
for i in np.arange (-0.2500000,0.2500000,theta):
         print kx+i,ky+i, kz,1000000
```

how can I add spaces and can get desired digits in output values?

Comment: output is in diffrent pattern like 0.25 0.25 0.00 1.0000000 and in next line it is 0.24 0.24 0.0 1.0000000

Comment: why do you import numpy twice?

Comment: Use the `format()` function to format your output.

Comment: Python has a couple of formatting tools.  That `print` indicates that you are using Py 2.7,so you may prefer the `%` style of formatting.  If the goal is to write this to a file, look at using `np.savetxt` with a custom `fmt` string.

Answer (score 0):

To print to a file you could do:

```
f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")

for i in np.arange (-0.2500000,0.2500000,theta):
         f.write((kx + i) + " " + (ky+ i) + " " + kz + " " + 1000000 + " \n")

f.close()
```

Comment: It worked with format( kx+i, '0.7f') + " " + ...... so on